# "please select valid startup item" Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, qt, user-interface

I am trying to run A 3D File Viewer based on OSG that use QT UI through visual studio but it shows "please select valid startup item" Visual Studio 2022

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpZKj.png)